# python change total time into minutes and subtract from the time 10 minutes without using any imports

Tags: python, time

The question includes that you need to have a main class consisting of fields, these fields are hours minutes, and seconds. I have to use this format and I can't import anything like datetime. the question is that I need to add 2 methods first to count full minutes in our time for example let's say we have a time of 1 hour and 22 minutes the code should give 82 minutes, so convert hours into minutes and then add it all in total which I already have done. and the second method is to remove 10 minutes from the time so I have to check that the time will not go in minus so here is my code I'm just stuck at the removing 10 minutes part but can't seem to add it all together.

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hour, min, sec):
        self.hour = hour
        self.min = min
        self.sec = sec
        if self.hour > 24 or self.min > 60 or self.sec > 60:
            exit()

    def minutes_in_full_time(self):
        return self.hour * 60 + self.min

    def remove_ten(self):
        if self.hour >= 23 and self.min >= 50 and self.sec >= 60:
            print("Add 10 min" + str(0) + ":" + str(0) + ":" + str(self.min - 60 - 10))
        elif self.hour < 23 and self.min >= 50 and self.sec >= 60:
            print("Add 10 min" + str(self.hour + 1) + ":" + str(0) + ":" + str(self.sec - 60 - 10))
        elif self.hour < 23 and self.min < 50 and self.sec >= 60:
            print("Add 10 min" + str(self.hour + 1) + ":" + str(self.min + 1) + ":" + str(self.sec - 60 - 10))
        else:
            print("Add 10 min" + str(self.hour) + ":" + str(self.min + 1) + ":" + str(self.sec - 60 - 10))

    def __del__(self):
        print("Видалено")


time1 = Time(6, 34, 22)
print("amount of minutes in hours", time1.minutes_in_full_time)
time1.remove_ten()
del time1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hour, min, sec):
        self.hour = hour
        self.min = min
        self.sec = sec
        if self.hour > 24 or self.min > 60 or self.sec > 60:
            exit()

    def minutes_in_full_time(self):
        return self.hour * 60 + self.min

    def remove_ten(self):
        if self.hour >= 1 and self.min < 10:
            print(" remove 10 min : " + str(self.hour - 1) + ":" + str(self.min + 60 - 10) + ":" + str(0))
        elif self.hour < 1 and self.min < 10:
            print(" remove 10 min : " + str(self.hour + 23) + ":" + str(self.min + 60 - 10) + ":" + str(0))
        else:
            print(" remove 10 min : " + str(self.hour) + ":" + str(self.min - 10) + ":" + str(0))

    def __del__(self):
        print("removed")


time1 = Time(0, 5, 5)
print("amount of minutes in hours ", time1.minutes_in_full_time())
time1.remove_ten()
del time1
time2 = Time(2, 45, 45)
print("amount of minutes in hours ", time2.minutes_in_full_time())
time2.remove_ten()
del time2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code:

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, h, m, s):
        self.h = h; self.m = m; self.s = s # Compiled Code
        # if self.h > 24 or self. m > 60 or self.s > 60: raise ValueError
    
    def time_to_minute(self):
        return self.h*60 + self.m + round(self.s/60, 2) # Round decimals to 2 digits

    def increase_time(self, new_h = 0, new_m = 0, new_s = 0):
        self.h += new_h; self.m += new_m; self.s += new_s;
        return self.time_to_minute()

time = Time(10, 34, 22)
time_in_minutes = time.time_to_minute()
time_change = time.increase_time(new_h = -10) # Subtract 10 minutes
```

Comment: the code doesnt seem to work for me because to me this looks like a C# code am I right ?

Comment: This is python, just compiled.

Comment: It is `python` and secondly there is no reason why it won't work. How does it look `C#`?

Comment: it just keeps telling me time() takes no arguments am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: just all the semicolons ( ; ) at the end of h m and s I used to use them in C# sorry I'm just new

Comment: It is `Time()` and secondly semi-colons `;` are used in almost every programming language. They are just used to differentiate between lines